# Azure Web App .NET Core Start Up Error - How to find cause

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have deployed a .NET core application to an Azure App Service, and I am getting a startup error (500.30). My application works locally, and the error logging is not providing enough information for me to troubleshoot the issue. How can I see more logging?

Comment: For reference to others, below answer serves as a step-by-step walkthrough of the one provided here: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/38950/http-error-50030-ancm-in-process-start-failure.html#:~:text=HTTP%20Error%20500.30%20%E2%80%93%20ANCM%20In-Process%20Start%20Failure%E2%80%9D,that%20is%20causing%20our%20application%20not%20to%20load.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a first step in troubleshooting ASP.NET Core on Azure App Services please see the following doc for published information on common app startup errors and instructions on how to diagnose errors when an app is deployed to Azure App Service or IIS: [Troubleshoot ASP.NET Core on Azure App Service and IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Often times ASP.NET Core startup errors are not accompanied with descriptive logs. Here is a step by step process to capture addtional logs:

1. Go to the SCM site -> https://yourapp.scm.azurewebsites.net
2. Click on the Debug Console tab at the top of the page and choose CMD
3. Navigate to site\wwwroot
4. Here look for web.config file and click the pencil icon to edit it
5. Edit the web.config as shown below:
   [image: Enable stdout]
6. Now browse the homepage of your site
7. You should see the startup failure error message
8. Now go back to the SCM site
9. Navigate to d:\home\LogFiles
10. You should see stdout_xxx_datetime.log as shown below:
    [image: Logs]
11. Click the pencil icon to view it
12. You should see the callstack and line# of the exception as shown below:
    [image: Callstack]

Comment: Thanks, this was really quick to implement. I see the error now when I browse to my homepage, looks like it is having trouble accessing some file... I'll take a look into it.